# Spring Social applicationURL setup exception

Tags: spring-social

For Spring Social version 1.1.0.RELEASE, I need to set up the applicationUrl for the ProviderSignInController, as my application (a Tomcat app) is hosted behind a proxy (Apache web server). According the [Spring Social document](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#enabling-provider-sign-in-with-code-providersignincontroller-code), I set it up as below:

```xml
<bean id="providerSignInController"
    class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ProviderSignInController">
    <property name="signInUrl" value="/accounts/login" />
    <property name="signUpUrl" value="/accounts/signup" />
    <property name="postSignInUrl" value="/accounts/profile" />
    <property name="applicationUrl" value="${applicationUrl}" />
</bean>
```

However, when deploying the application, I get an exception in Tomcat catalina.out saying:

```
PropertyAccessException 1:
org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property
'applicationUrl' threw exception; nested exception is
java.lang.NullPointerException>org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name
'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0'
defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]:
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating
bean with name 'providerSignInController' defined in ServletContext
resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Error setting property values;
nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested
PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1:
org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property
'applicationUrl' threw exception; nested exception is
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
```

Any suggestions please? Thanks.

Comment: you already set up the `applicationUrl` in your properties right?

Comment: Yes, as recommended by the Spring Social document (http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#enabling-provider-sign-in-with-code-providersignincontroller-code), the value of the application URL is externalized in a properties file. By the way, if I don't set up property applicationUrl in bean providerSignInController's declaration, the bean can be created with no problem. That is, there is no problem with properties signInUrl, signUpUrl and postSignInUrl.

Comment: Then, could you show us the properties file and also how you configure the spring to read the properties file? well the other properties (like signInUrl, signUpUrl) doesn't have any problem because you set those value directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a bug with class ProviderSignInController in Spring Social version 1.1.0.RELEASE. In class ProviderSignInController, connectSupport is created after properties being set:

```java
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    this.connectSupport = new ConnectSupport(sessionStrategy);
    this.connectSupport.setUseAuthenticateUrl(true);
};
```

Therefore when method setApplicationUrl is invoked, connectSupport is still null.

Now when I configure it in the way shown below, it works. Or if I revert to version 1.0.3.RELEASE, it works fine too.

```xml
<bean id="providerSignInController"
    class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ProviderSignInController">
    <property name="signInUrl" value="/accounts/login" />
    <property name="signUpUrl" value="/accounts/signup" />
    <property name="postSignInUrl" value="/accounts/profile" />
</bean>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="providerSignInController" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="setApplicationUrl" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <bean class="java.lang.String">
                <constructor-arg value="${applicationUrl}" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**Follow-up**

This problem has been resolved in Spring Social version 1.1.3.RELEASE. In class ProviderSignInController, method afterPropertiesSet has been updated to:

```java
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    this.connectSupport = new ConnectSupport(sessionStrategy);
    this.connectSupport.setUseAuthenticateUrl(true);
    if (this.applicationUrl != null) {
        this.connectSupport.setApplicationUrl(applicationUrl);
    }
};
```

As a result, the workaround of configuration given above (by the way, would not work with Spring Social version 1.1.3.RELEASE any more) can now be simplified to:

```xml
<bean id="providerSignInController"
    class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ProviderSignInController">
    <property name="signInUrl" value="/accounts/login" />
    <property name="signUpUrl" value="/accounts/signup" />
    <property name="postSignInUrl" value="/accounts/profile" />
    <property name="applicationUrl" value="${applicationUrl}" />
</bean>
```